# How to make an array's derived type accept aggregate initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, stdarray

For example

```
class A : public std::array<int, 3>
{
};
```

And

```
A a{1, 2, 3}; // failed currently.
```

How to make an array's derived type accept aggregate initialization?

Comment: Can't you just `typedef`? Otherwise you will have to provide a ctor.

Comment: C++17 isn't here just yet...

Comment: Inheriting std::array is a bad idea to start with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could provide a variadic template constructor as follows:

```
class A : public std::array<int, 3> {
public:
  template<typename... Args> constexpr A(Args&& ...args) 
    : std::array<int, 3>{{std::forward<Args>(args)...}} {}
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/beff2e5a2d32a1ee)

Edit:

The following version works also on Visual Studio:

```
class A : public std::array<int, 3> {
public:
    template<typename... Args> constexpr A(Args&& ...args) 
      : std::array<int, 3>(std::array<int,3>{std::forward<Args>(args)...}) {}
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/HHQFJ53739)

Comment: That's the better answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As others pointed out in comments, this won't work for `std::array` because `std::array` doesn't contain constructor taking `initializer_list`. But it might be useful for other containers that have constructor taking `initializer_list`, for example `std::vector`.

You can use *inheriting constructor*(since C++11):

```
class A: public std::vector<int,3>
{
      using std::vector<int,3>::vector;
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work in VS2015. Not sure other compilers.

Comment: It is delegate constructors

Comment: @user1899020 No, it isn't :)

Comment: @user1899020 compiles on gcc-6

Comment: Sure it compiles now. But std::array doesn't have any constructors to inherit. It uses aggregate initialization.

Comment: Inheriting constructor doesn't enable aggregate initialization

Answer (score 0):

Just define a constructor like that:

```
A(std::array<int, 3>);
```

example:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct A : public std::array<int, 3>
{
    A(std::array<int, 3>    a) :
        std::array<int, 3>{a}
    {
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    A   a({1, 2, 3});

    std::cout << a[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << a[1] << "\n";
    std::cout << a[2] << "\n";
}
```

That is not an aggregate initialization, but it is an "as if"...